# How to pass UIButton to a function and create there...?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

Question may look so stupid, just got problem in some basics of objective C. I'm aware objective C only support pass by value however my requirement needs to pass address. I have a UIButton member variable (iVar) and I'm passing these to a function and trying to alloc init inside the function using parameters like below...

Function Call:

```
[self create_button : ivar_btn];
```

Definition:

```
- (void) create_button : (UIButton*) button
{
    // Create button
    button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    [button setTitle:@"00/00/0000" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [self.add_scroll_view addSubview:button];
}
```

So without pass by reference in objective C, how do I handle this case?

Please correct me if I understood anything wrong.

**NOTE: Create button is a common code, I have been using this to create buttons at run time depend on req.**

Thanx

Comment: what is the problem with your above code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is useless implementation and I have not tried it but still.

```
UIButton *ivar_btn = nil;   
    [self create_button : &ivar_btn];
- (void) create_button : (UIButton**) button
    {
        // Create button
        *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
        [*button setTitle:@"00/00/0000" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [self.add_scroll_view addSubview:*button];
    }
```

Comment: Are you sure it will compile?

Comment: @Newbee have you tried it before you asked? ;) copy/paste. It is working in my test.

Comment: I have tried it shown error like "Cannot initilize parameter of type autoreleasing* with strong.. something like that"

Comment: okay, you are using ARC, do you? in this case it's maybe better to use a common return value

Comment: Ya you are right, I have returned value and fixed my problem by returning value. Still if any way to use Pass by reference it could be more handy in my case.

Comment: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#releasenotes/ObjectiveC/RN-TransitioningToARC/Introduction/Introduction.html -> **ARC Enforces New Rules**. one more reason for me not to change :P

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code, it is working fine for me. just you missing one thing. Setting its frame.

Here is how I amend your code and works fine for me. Hope it will work for you as well.

```
UIButton *btn = [[UIButton alloc] init];
[self create_button:btn];
```

and Function/Method:

```
- (void) create_button : (UIButton*) button
{
    // Create button
    button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    [button setTitle:@"00/00/0000" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [button setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100,100)];
    [self.view addSubview:button];
}
```

works fine

Comment: I'm using Auto Layout feature.. No need to set frame.. I handled it in constraint way...

Answer (score 0):

Try this....

```
- (void) create_button : (UIButton*) button
{
    // Create button
    UIButton *tmpButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    tmpButton = button;
    [self.add_scroll_view addSubview:tmpButton];
}
```

Comment: I am not supposed to use tmpButton inside function.